# Python RegExp capture Integer in between certain pattern acts not the same as normal?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, regular-language

I want to capture Integer in between certain string.
My Regular Expression String is
`re_str = "HOWMUCH？*\s*＿*\s*(\s*(\d+)\s*)＿*\s*USD"`

```
target_text = " 1. HOWMUCH？＿＿10＿ USD
 1. HOWMUCH？＿20＿USD
 1. HOWMUCH？30＿＿ USD
 1. HOWMUCH？＿＿40＿＿＿ USD
 1. HOWMUCH？  50 USD
 1. HOWMUCH？ ＿＿60＿＿＿USD"
# I need to capture all int: 10, 20, 30 ... 60
```

Works well in here: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PHFjbg/1/)

I have tried `re.findall`

```
m = re.findall(r'{}'.format(re_str), target_text)
m:  [('20', '20')]
```

also tried `re.search`, got the same results.
[python repl](https://repl.it/@yuching/PowderblueOvalBackslash)

Environment: Python2.7

**SOLVED**
I modified RegExp to `HOWMUCH？*[\s]*[＿]*[\s]*(\s*(\d+)\s*)[＿]*[\s]*USD`
then it works !

Comment: [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall): *If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.*

Comment: I modified the question, it's a python regexp question, not the behavior on re.findall() function.

Comment: Note that your [original regex](https://regex101.com/r/XpKeQt/1) also works the same, there is no issue. Just when you use 2 capturing groups you will have a list of tuples in the output.  Why did you use two capturing groups? `？[＿\s]*(\d+)[＿_\s]*USD` also works, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MdtCv1/1), and there will be only numbers in the list.